# Using POST for all functions in REST protocol

Tags: php

Is it wrong to use POST for everything in REST? I know POST is for updating and creating but what if I use it for SELECTS and DELETS as well? What I basically need is a web service that can do CRUD operations to a database. Im using PHP. Also, what if I use query strings to do the POST request instead of using JSON or XML?

Comment: Why would you *not* use the appropriate HTTP verbs?

Comment: I was just asking if it was wrong.

Comment: Facebook used GET for all their functions. That included delete/update as well.

Comment: @Indy: How can it be wrong? In what sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using POST for all operations, you can't really call it REST anymore.

So it's not wrong, but it's not REST either :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it wrong to use POST for everything in REST?

You can't use POST for everything in REST (e.g. only for requests, not responses), so the question about wrong or right is not a valid question.

> I know POST is for updating and creating but what if I use it for SELECTS and DELETS as well?

It normally just works.

> What I basically need is a web service that can do CRUD operations to a database.

That's fine.

> Im using PHP.

That's fine, too. PHP hast support for the HEAD, GET and POST method. For the PUT and DELETE methods you need to do a little bit more coding.

> Also, what if I use query strings to do the POST request instead of using JSON or XML?

You use query strings instead of JSON/XML request bodies. REST does not specify the protocol, so you can do whatever pleases you. Using "query strings" might be a good idea with PHP as PHP supports those out of the box. But it depends what you use for a handler or what you want to support.

As your questions are very broad, you might want to read some basic description of REST first before so you can more specifically ask: [A Brief Introduction to REST](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's wrong.  If you are using POST for anything other than updating you aren't actually following the REST convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can eat soup with fork but why? Anyway you can use any method, just don't call it REST protocol.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong to use POST for calls that are meant to be repeatable.

POST calls are never cached but your select calls should be cache-able (and repeatable) so you shouldn't be using POST for them.

But there's no technical reason why you can't force everything through POST, (particularly as DELETE isn't supported across all browsers), but it does mean that caching won't work for any of your calls, and also that your users may not be able to refresh a web page without being asked to confirm page reload if POST calls have been made to create it.

Answer (score 0):

At this REST tutorial [here](http://rest.elkstein.org/) the 4th article in the series says:

> For creation, updating, and deleting data, use POST requests. (POST can also be used for read-only queries, as noted above, when complex parameters are required.)

Of course GET is usually used for read-only queries, so putting it all together, if complexity is the default assumption, which is kind of a handy assumption when no threshold between complexity and simplicity is stated, then this guy who is enough an authority to write a whole series on REST is saying that it's okay to POST everything. May be caches make some assumptions about responses to various HTTP verbs that might be beneficial but if your application does not benefit from caching (indeed, might be harmed by it, so disable it or do something so your application does not suffer from it) then I don't know if there's any problem at all.